# Handsontable, set number of visible rows in a cell

Tags: row, cell, handsontable

I am having issues finding the setting in the handsontable that will set the number of visible rows in a cell. The problem is I have some rows with 15 to 20 lines in a cell and it is making my table huge. I would like to be able to set the max number of visible rows in a cell and give the user the ability to scroll in a cell to view the rest of its content.

Thanks for the help!

Answering the comment below of what is meant by multiple lines in a cell:

This is one line:

```
Example of one line
```

This is multiline:

```
multiline1
multiline2
multiline3
```

Comment: what do you mean by "lines in a cell"?

Answer (score 1):

In the handsontable.full.css file i added 'white-space: nowrap;' and that hid the extra lines in a cell. I also added 'text-overflow: ellipsis;' to add an ellipsis to the end of cells that were going to be multiline for a cleaner look.

The following is the block in the handsontable.full.css file that I changed:

```
.handsontable th,
.handsontable td {
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  height: 22px;
  empty-cells: show;
  line-height: 21px;
  padding: 0 4px 0 4px;
  /* top, bottom padding different than 0 is handled poorly by FF with HTML5 doctype */
  background-color: #FFF;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline-width: 0;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* preserve new line character in cell */
}
```

Comment: I think what OP wants is to have a scrollpane in the cells though

Comment: also, changing the handsontable css file might not be the best idea since any updates to this will erase your changes. It's always best to override the css rather than change it. Of course in this case, I think handsontable might not allow you to change td css so it might be the only solution

Comment: i looked and didn't see an option for changing the td css but that doesn't mean there isn't one. Also, I do agree, changing the css file isn't ideal but it did get the job done.

Comment: Oh yeah what you normally do is create a new file and load it after the handsontable one so that it overrides the settings. That's what I meant. But yeah, HOT does some dynamic CSS settings that override these regardless, making touching the CSS something really hard to do lately

Answer (score 1):

If you do in fact want to scroll then what you should be doing is two things. First you need to set a `width` on your hot instance so that your columns don't get too large. In fact, I would also set the `colWidths` option.

After that, all you need is to add the CSS rule:

```
.handsontable td {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

This will cause the overflowing text, like multiple lines, to show a scroll bar. To test this yourself, right click on one of the cells that you're talking about and click on "Inspect element". On the right side, find the "Styles" tab and in the element.style block add the property I wrote above. You'll see it working.